# Javascript (Typescript): for loop not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am working in Ionic 2 and I'm trying to make a for loop to show certain data.  But it is acting very strange.

I currently have an array of "time left" using moment.js

```
var dur = moment.duration( moment(date).diff(moment()) );
let yearsRemain = dur.years();
let monthsRemain = dur.months();
let daysRemain = dur.days();
let hoursRemain = dur.hours();
let minutesRemain = dur.minutes();
let secondsRemain = dur.seconds();

var dateArray = [
  yearsRemain,
  monthsRemain,
  daysRemain,
  hoursRemain,
  minutesRemain,
  secondsRemain
]
```

If I were to output the `dateArray` like `this.timeString = dateArray.join(",");` and show `timeString` in my html, I can see the following values:

```
0,  0,  0,-17,-46, -3  //17 hours ago
0,  0,  0, 10,  7, 47  //in 10 hours 7 minutes
0,  0,  2,  1,  9, 35  //in 2 days and 1 hour
```

Now, I iterate through the array and I try to get the two largest values.  I'm trying to show a string like I have in the comments above.  If it is in the past, I want to show just the largest value.

```
for(var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
  if(dateArray[i] > 0){
    //If the event is in the future
    this.state = "future";
    this.timePrimary = dateArray[i];
    this.timePrimaryType = this.typeOfTime(i, dateArray[i]);
    this.timeSecondary = dateArray[i+1] !== 0 ? dateArray[i+1] : dateArray[i+2];
    this.timeSecondaryType = dateArray[i+1] !== 0 ? this.typeOfTime(i+1, dateArray[i+1]) : this.typeOfTime(i+2, dateArray[i+2]);
    break;
  } else if(dateArray[i] < 0) {
    //If the event is in the past
    this.state = "past";
    this.timePrimary = dateArray[i] * (-1);
    this.timePrimaryType = this.typeOfTime(i, (dateArray[i] * (-1))) + " ago";
    break;
  } else {
    i++
  }
}
```

This loop goes through each array item and should catch the first array item that isn't a `0`.  If it's larger than 0, the event is in the future and I want to capture that number and the next (if the next is zero, find the next, I'm going to upgrade this part soon).

**Here's the problem**

For some reason, it's skipping the `hours` part of the array when hours is the largest number.  Take the second example from above: `0,  0,  0, 10,  7, 47`.  All I see is `7 minutes and 47 seconds` when it should read `10 hours and 7 minutes`.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Just in case you feel like asking, here's the `typeOfType` function:

```
typeOfTime(type, num) {
var display;
var plur = num === 1 ? "" : "s";
switch(type) {
  case 0:
    display = "Year" + plur;
    break;
  case 1:
    display = "Month" + plur;
    break;
  case 2:
    display = "Day" + plur;
    break;
  case 3:
    display = "Hour" + plur;
    break;
  case 4:
    display = "Minute" + plur;
    break;
  case 5:
    display = "Second" + plur;
    break;
}
return display;
```

}

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i` at the bottom of the loop?

Comment: @torazaburo The `else` statement is basically saying `if the value of this array item is equal to 0, look at the next array item`

Comment: @torazaburo, your comment was dead on.  I had the biggest brain fart ever.  No reason to increment a loop inside a for loop... Thank you!

Comment: Maybe http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/ or http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/ and similar?

Comment: @DrColossos, I tried using that, and it works great, but I wanted to see the largest 2 times.  from and from now only show the single largest time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `else` statement in your code is incrementing the counter `i` and that is causing the loop to skip the next item in the array when it hits a `0`.
That is why `10` is skipped after `0`. 
Remove that part and it should work.

```
for(var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
  if(dateArray[i] > 0){
    //If the event is in the future
    this.state = "future";
    this.timePrimary = dateArray[i];
    this.timePrimaryType = this.typeOfTime(i, dateArray[i]);
    this.timeSecondary = dateArray[i+1] !== 0 ? dateArray[i+1] : dateArray[i+2];
    this.timeSecondaryType = dateArray[i+1] !== 0 ? this.typeOfTime(i+1, dateArray[i+1]) : this.typeOfTime(i+2, dateArray[i+2]);
    break;
  } else if(dateArray[i] < 0) {
    //If the event is in the past
    this.state = "past";
    this.timePrimary = dateArray[i] * (-1);
    this.timePrimaryType = this.typeOfTime(i, (dateArray[i] * (-1))) + " ago";
    break;
  } else {
    //do nothing... let the loop to go on.
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow.  that's a facepalm right there...  Thank you for helping me understand a basic loop again!  Answer will be accepted in 7 minutes